# Hide div and show another divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I just want to show a div when someone click "add" button. If he clicks that "add" button again, needs to hide the current one and show another div. It also needs to show the approved div list on top area. If someone clicks the top area approved div, need to load the div again.

[image]

I try to hide and show on click but no luck. (I'm bit new to jquery and I know this is pretty basic code.)

Here is the fiddle [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jayD2/1Lqj9e5h/1/)

```js
$('.add-box').click(function() {
  $('.test-div-2').show();
});

$('.add-box').click(function() {
  $('.test-div-1').hide();
});
```

```css
.test-div-1,
.test-div-2,
.test-div-3 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test-div-1">1</div>
<div class="test-div-2">2</div>
<div class="test-div-3">3</div>

<a class="add-box">Add</a>
```

Comment: you din't added jQuery file in your fiddle

Comment: you haven't written any code in fiddle . https://jsfiddle.net/1Lqj9e5h/3/

Comment: So, on first click test-div-1 will appear.If I again click test-div-2 will appear?

Answer (score 2):

Do below things:-

1.Add jQuery library before your script code.

2.Wrap your code inside `$(document).ready(function(){..});` (needed when script code is added above the HTML. if script code is added at the bottom of the page then wrapping is not needed).

3.Do `show(),hide()` in single click itself.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.add-box').click(function() {
    $('.test-div-2').show();
    $('.test-div-1').hide();
  });
});
```

```css
.test-div-1,
.test-div-2,
.test-div-3{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test-div-1">1</div>
<div class="test-div-2">2</div>
<div class="test-div-3">3</div>

<a class="add-box">Add</a>
```

Fiddle example:- https://jsfiddle.net/rrj1818a/

***Note:-***

***If you want to show one-by-one then do like below:-***

https://jsfiddle.net/87re6avo/

Comment: As of jQuery 3.0 `$(document).ready(handler)` is no longer recommended. Use `$(handler)`

Comment: I need to show one by one. I think this is the thing I want https://jsfiddle.net/87re6avo/ How can I Show added divs in top like my screenshot?

Comment: @MarkNsu  i have added a note section with an example link. did you checked that? any issue there?

Comment: user6037606  i have added a note section with an example link. did you checked that? I hope that's the solution you are looking into. Let me know

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="test-div active">1</div>
<div class="test-div">2</div>
<div class="test-div">3</div>
<a class="add-box">Add</a>



$('.add-box').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var $current = $('.test-div.active');
var $next = $current.next();

$current.removeClass('active');



if(!$next.length) {
$next = $('.test-div').first();


}



$next.addClass('active');

});
```

Comment: I just loop if you reach last `div` in case if you don't  want you can replace it with `return` inside `if` block.